# why the label of ObjectChoiceField hide when background is black in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am using ObjectChoiceField actually My label is hide when I use black background ?I am using this example

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Drop_down_menus_1177778_11.jsp

My text is **"Day of week "** is hide due to black background ?
How to give some margin to given label **"Day of week "*

```
package mypackage;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ObjectChoiceField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;

/**
 * A class extending the MainScreen class, which provides default standard
 * behavior for BlackBerry GUI applications.
 */
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
    /**
     * Creates a new MyScreen object
     */
    public MyScreen()
    {        
        // Set the displayed title of the screen       
        setTitle("Drop-down List Demo"); 
        String choices[] = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};
        int iSetTo = 0;
        VerticalFieldManager vfm=new VerticalFieldManager(){
            protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                graphics.fillRect(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), 800);
                super.paint(graphics);
            }
        };
        vfm.add(new ObjectChoiceField("Day of the week",choices,iSetTo){
            protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                super.paint(graphics);
            }
        });



        add(vfm);

    }
}
```

Comment: Answered here?  http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Why-drop-downis-not-display-in-blackberry/td-p/2700917

Comment: my second question is how to set margin ..if I want to show label on left side

Comment: @user2648752 left side mean..??? can explain a bit more.